# GDB: How to remove a variable from the auto display

Tags: gdb

I stumbled upon the auto-display functionality of gdb, which is pretty powerful and convenient. After calling

```
(gdb) display/i $pc
(gdb) display $rax
```

the watched values are displayed automatically after every step:

```
(gdb) si
0x0804805e in print_loop_start ()
2: $rax = 0
1: x/i $pc
=> 0x804805e <print_loop_start+6>:  mov    0x4(%ebp,%eax,4),%ecx
```

But how can I "unwatch" the value in $rax, if it is no longer of interest?

Comment: "Use "undisplay" to cancel display requests previously made."

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Gdb help for display says:

> "Use `undisplay` to cancel display requests previously made."

So if you do `display a`, then `display b`, and `display c` gdb will give numbers to this requests (which you can see by issuing replay with no arguments). Then you can use this numbers with `undisplay`.

Example:

```
(gdb) display a
1: a = 32767
(gdb) display b
2: b = 0
(gdb) display c
3: c = 0
(gdb) undisplay 2
(gdb) step
6     b = 2;
1: a = 1
3: c = 0
```

Details in [gdb documentation](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Auto-Display.html).

Answer (score 1):

Note that you can also temporarily hide a disp output using:

```
disable display dnums…
```

And re-enable with:

```
enable display dnums…
```

Comment: Don't know why the downvotes, this is useful additional information I didn't know!   You can use it with no arguments to completely disable and re-enable all displays: `disable display` and `enable display`

Comment: @bogatyr that's why I added it 6 years later. Thanks for the support 